# Finding the inverse of linear transformations in $\mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

For each of the following linear transformations, find the inverse if it exists, or explain why there is no inverse.

(a) $T : \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^3$ where $T(v)$ is the reflection of $v$ around the plane $x + 2y + 3z = 0$.

(b) $T : \mathbb{R}^3 \to\mathbb{R}^3$ where $T(v)$ is the projection of v along the vector $(1, 2, 3)$

(c) $T : \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^3$ where $T(v) = Av$,
$$A =
\begin{pmatrix}
        1 & 1 & b \\
        0 & 1 & 1 \\
        0 & 0 & 1 \\
        \end{pmatrix},$$

and $b$ is a real number.

These are very confusing to me because I never learned linear transformations in depth. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This is a "homework style question," in that it appears that you have simply posted a homework problem and are asking for us to solve it.  These kinds of questions, whether they are actual homework questions or not, tend to receive a poor reception here.  I would suggest that you edit your question to give some indication as to what you have tried, and where, specifically, you are struggling.  It might also be a good idea to focus on just one of the three problems that you have asked about.

Comment: This is a repost of [Inverse of Linear Transformations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2468550/inverse-of-linear-transformations). Please stop doing that. And asking people to solve your homework is **definitely not** going to help you understand linear transformations in depth. Instead ask about what you don't understand in your textbook or course materials!

Answer (score 0):

If you have $x,y \in \mathbb R^3$ such as $y=Ax$, the inverse transformation (if it exists) is given by $x=A^{-1}y$. Find the transformation matrix for parts a and b (you already have it for c). If the determinant is 0, you don't have an inverse. If it's not zero, calculate the inverse of the matrix